# Integrating GCS on a staging Jekyll website

Tags: search-engine, jekyll, google-custom-search

We currently have a staging website, which has an IP address like  xx.xx.xxx.xxx  and we would like to have integrated and tested GCS on it before pushing it live. Is it possible?

Otherwise, is there any alternative to GCS to add a search bar in a Jekyll blog without using plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## PART I: Google

Google custom search cannot index an application that isn't available to the internet.

No, that's not [entirely true](https://www.google.com/work/search/solutions/index.html#intranet). You *can* arrange something with Google (in theory, never done it) but it doesn't look easy. Or cheap.

You could set up a custom search for an unrelated site and embed those results in your local page, if you want to test out CSS prior to launch.

Remember, Google Custom Search also comes with ads, unless you pay. And the results tend to look like they came from Google.

## PART II: Alternatives

I've looked into this extensively and I haven't come up with a good answer. Here are some not-so-good answers:

1) Tapir Search. This actually worked pretty well, but appears to have died. They do have recent twitter activity, however, so maybe worth checking back in a bit. [twitter](https://twitter.com/tapirgo). It's basically a (free) front end for an elasticsearch server. I think. Neat service, obviously not super-dependable.

2) Go javascript. [Lunr](http://lunrjs.com/) for example. There are many, many similar solutions available. Sadly, they are client-side and doing a full-text search on even a smallish blog type site can be very slow. Works okay if you limit the search to titles, but then...you're only searching titles.

3) Build a search engine server. Maybe some breed of [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/). Upside: very robust search while keeping the snappy response of a flat HTML site. Downside: building and maintaining a search engine server is difficult, expensive and probably overkill.

4) Hosted search engine. [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) for example. They're basically doing 3) for you. Relatively expensive (~$50/month) but well worth the cost, because, seriously, search engine servers are finicky and prone to explosions. I've never gone this route with Jekyll because I've never had a Jekyll project I was quite that serious about, but I did consider it.

If anyone has anything to add, I'd love to hear it. This question has been irritating me for a while.